# addthis plugin email form customiization

Tags: forms, email, plugins, service, addthis

In our project we are using the free version of Addthis, and in the specification when using the email form, the customer wants to see the images of all products in the page (for example in the shopping basket page), he also wants to select in the form the images (products) that he will send in the email.

I have searched for that but I can't find a solution for this.

So I'm asking if Addthis can do the customization in the email form in the free version, or in the full version ? if yes can you tell how ? or he can't do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

We asked Addthis support team, they said we can't do that.

The response :
"Hi there,

Thank you for contacting AddThis support. Unfortunately this feature is not supported by AddThis yet. Anyway I will pass your feedback to our product team to consider this in one of our future release.

Thanks!"